# AngularJS retrieve data outside request

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have a problem accessing data outside my service request. See my code below. The variable works within the service request. But when i want to acces the variable outside the request, i'm getting a undefined variable.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
   API.getUser($scope.email, $scope.password).then(function(data) {
            $scope.user_id = (data.id);
            console.log($scope.user_id) // this works 

        });

  console.log($scope.user_id);  // <--- Here i'm getting undefined.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $apply() on scope in the callback function.

```
API.getUser($scope.email, $scope.password).then(function(data) {
            $scope.user_id = (data.id);
            $scope.$apply(); // <----- Here
            console.log($scope.user_id) 

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to API.getUser is an asynchronous call and the code below that executes before the callback executes. That is why $scope.user_id is undefined. You can do anything you want to do with the variable inside the success callback and pass it to functions if you need to work more with this user_id.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is with the Javascript behavior for asyncs operations and the use of Promises ($q), when the interpreter run the code, does something like this:

1) Make this ajax request (An async operation), and return a Promise

```
API.getUser($scope.email, $scope.password)
```

2) Register the function in the Promise, to be executed when the operation ends

```
  .then(function(data) {
     $scope.user_id = (data.id);
     console.log($scope.user_id) // this works 
   });
```

3) Print the current value of $scope.user_id

```
console.log($scope.user_id);
```

Print undefined because in this moment the Async operation are not finished

4) On some time the Async operation finish and execute this code

```
$scope.user_id = (data.id);
console.log($scope.user_id) // this works
```

In the last part the $scope.user_id was set, and the console.log print the correct value.

Comment: I dont understand it?